# Ensemble de/des, liste de/des

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour, j'étais en train de regarder [ce site](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C3%A9r%C3%A9monie), et cette phrase m'a interpelé:

> Ensemble des formes extérieures et régulières du culte religieux, des célébrations mystiques.

`Ensemble des`?

Je sais qu'à un moment un collègue ma repris parce que j'ai dit `une liste des choses à faire`. Il m'a corrigé `une liste de choses à faire` (sans explication derrière , donc je ne me sens pas forcément moins bête).

Par conséquent, je suis assez confus en ce qui concerne l'utilisation de "de" et "des" derrière "ensemble" et "liste".

Y a-t-il une règle qui s'applique ?

Merci bien

Comment: On dit  plutôt ***la** liste **des** choses à faire* en particulier (la liste est définie) mais ***une** liste **de** choses à faire* en général (la liste est indéfinie).

Comment: Merci @jlliagre très clair. Et pour `Ensemble des formes extérieures` svp?

Comment: *Ensemble des formes* : on y trouve toutes les formes; *ensemble de formes* : on y trouve un certain nombre de formes.